# LinkedIn share button error

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

I am trying to dynamically change LinkedIn share button. The button changes the layout but the share count is displayed as 0 and there is an error in console.

**Error / Issue**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Clarification: Error is thrown by LinkedIn script.

**Code**

```
jQuery(document.ready(function($){
    $.getScript( 'https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js' );
    $( '#li_counter_type' ).on( 'change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val(); // none, right, top
        $( '#linkedin-container' ).html( '<script id="li" type="IN/Share" data-counter="'+ val +'"></script>' );
        if (typeof (IN) != 'undefined') {
            IN.parse();
        }
    });
});
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Looks like `$( '#linkedin-container' )` isn't finding an element, and is therefore `undefined`. Did you make a typo?

Comment: Cross-checked everywhere and there is no typo.

Comment: Open the JS console (F12) and try `$( '#linkedin-container' )`. What do you get?

Comment: @analytalica I will try but I don't think there is any issue with that. When I remove only the script tag and not the span tag created on initialization then there is no error on re-initialization. But then I get multiple buttons. At the moment I am just hiding additional buttons but looking for a proper fix.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error is thrown by LinkedIn script.